# I set token in cookies axios get token undefined until i refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here my axios file

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const token = Cookies.get("token");

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, // Replace with your API base URL
  timeout: 10000, // Optional: Set a timeout for requests
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    ...(token && { "x-access-token": token }),
  },
});

export default api;
```

When I login I set `token` in cookies. `token` set but axios doesn't get it until I refresh the page. On page refresh axios re-render so axios has `token` from cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the token value from cookies only once when creating the `api` instance when the code is loaded.

Use a [request interceptor](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors) to read and inject the current token value when requests are made.

Example:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, // Replace with your API base URL
  timeout: 10000, // Optional: Set a timeout for requests
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  const token = Cookies.get("token");

  if (token) {
    config.headers["x-access-token"] = token;
  }

  return config;
});

export default axiosInstance;
```